# Binding a Combo Box Edit to a list in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, devexpress

I'm trying to bind a combo box to a list of items but I'm unsure about how to do it. I need to do it in XAML following Mvvm pattern and I can use DevExpress. I was trying that:

```
 <dxg:GridControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskView}" >
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns >
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project" FieldName="Project" 
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectCode, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True">

              <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxSettings DisplayMember="Project" ValueMember="ProductName" ItemTemplate="{Binding Path=Projects}" />
              </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectDescription}" AllowEditing="False"/>

        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView MultiSelectMode="Row" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedTasks}" 
                       ShowAutoFilterRow="False" ShowTotalSummary="True" 
                       AllowEditing="True" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

This code seems right to me but I can't use ItemTemplate="{Binding Path=Projects}" because ComboBoxSettings is not a dependency property. This code worked and I wanted to do something similar but within the gridcontrol:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentEmployeeName}" ItemsSource="Binding Path=EmployeeView}">
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxStyleSettings />
                    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Can anyone give me a clue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Being I don't have any doc for DevExpress controls, I can't give a thorough answer. However, I think **`ComboBoxSettings.ItemTemplate` is NOT the items binding**; it's probably how **each item will be displayed**.

Comment: Have you tried with the DataGrid? There's an example of using a combo-box with the DataGrid here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319662/how-do-i-bind-a-datagridcomboboxcolumn-to-entityframework-using-mvvm/9376563#9376563.  Maybe the same technique is applicable to the DX grid control.

Comment: I made a typo with ItemTemplate: I tried ItemSOurce too but is still wrong. I'll check tomorow if I can use this example, as is written to mvvm light and I use devexpress, but might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ComboBoxEditSettings](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsSettingsComboBoxEditSettingstopic) instead of the ComboBoxSettings:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="...">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"  ... />
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```